# php mayor en un arreglo

Tags: php, array, foreach

Tengo un arreglo el siguiente

```
$renglon=


140 82

89 134

90 110
```

todos los valores de lado izquierdo pertenecen a P1 y los del lado derecho a P2 al recorrerlo con mi foreach puedo separarlo y `sepa[0]>sepa[1]` es p1 si no es p2 hasta ahi todo bien me dice quien es mayor si p1 o p2  igual resta los dos valores el primero renglón da 58 el segundo 45 y el tercero 20 entonces el mayor de esos vendor siendo el 58 y respecto a esa resta el mayor sería 140 =a P1

```
foreach ($renglon as $key => $value) {
    $separada = explode(' ', $value);
    if ($sepa[0]>$sepa[1]) {
        $P1= 'P1';
    }else{
        $P2 = 'P2’;
    }
    //echo $jugador;
    $restas = abs($separada[0]-$separada[1]);
}
```

Mi respuesta debe de ser P1 58 y es lo que no se como sacarlo ya que la función max no me sirve

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

Ahora creo que quieres esto:

```
<?php
$renglon= [
    "140 82", 
    "89 134", 
    "90 110"
];

$P1 = [];
$P2 = [];

foreach ($renglon as $value) {
    $sepa = explode(' ', $value);
    if ($sepa[0]>$sepa[1]) {
        $P1[] = $sepa[0] - $sepa[1];
    } else {
        $P2[] = $sepa[1] - $sepa[0];
    }
}

rsort($P1);
rsort($P2);

if($P1[0] > $P2[0]) {
    $resultado = 'P1 '.$P1[0];
} else {
    $resultado = 'P2 '.$P2[0];
}

echo $resultado;   // P1 58
```

### Explicación detallada

- Partimos de la base de que tienes un array de valores separados por espacios en $renglon
- Inicializamos las variables $P1 y $P2 antes del bucle foreach para indicar que serán array, que después, dentro del bucle, iremos rellenando
- Iniciamos un bucle donde desechamos directamente los números de indice pues la pregunta no los pide, y lo escribimos así:

```php
foreach ($renglon as $value) {
```

- Separamos los valores separados por un espacio gracias a explode() y comprobamos si entre dichos valores el primero (P1) es mayor que el segundo (P2), en caso contrario saltamos al `else`
- Dentro del condicional agregamos el resultado de la diferencia de P1 menos P2 en la variable de array $P1 previamente creada, o si hemos saltado al `else` entonces agregamos el resultado de la diferencia de P2 menos P1 en la variable de array $P2 previamente creada, y así con todos los valores del $renglon
- Al salir del bucle ordenamos los array $P1 y $P2 por valores mediante el uso de la función [rsort()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.rsort.php), obteniendo de esta forma que el valor más grande será el primero de cada array
- Ahora debemos calcular cual de ambos valores máximos es superior al otro, y lo hacemos mediante otro condicional:

```
if($P1[0] > $P2[0]) {
```

y hacemos la asignación del resultado a la variable $resultado.

- Mostramos el resultado mediante un `echo` después del condicional.

Comment: Si ese resultado queria pero tambien queria saber a quien le correspondia esa ganada no se si me explico si a P1 o a P2 ya que en ese el mayor es p1 por lo tanto seria mi resultado p1 58

Comment: Acabo de modificar mi respuesta, comprueba si te sirve ahora, gracias